# How to create new column based on multiple when conditions over window in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `spark` dataframe

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,2,2], 'min_col': [2,2,3,4,5,6], 'raw': [1,5,2,3,4,3],
'max_col': [3,4,5,6,7,8]})
```

I want to create a new column `new_col` which will be `1` if the `min(raw) < min(min_col)` or if the `max(raw) > min(max_col)`, otherwise `0`, **by** **`id`**

I tried

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window.partitionBy('id')
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
foo.withColumn('new_col', 
        f.when((f.min(f.col('raw')) < f.min(f.col('min_col'))) |
               (f.max(f.col('raw')) > f.min(f.col('max_col'))),f.lit(1)).otherwise(f.lit(0)).over(w))
```

But I get an error `id is not an aggregate function`. Any ideas ?

Comment: There is a mistake in first line, arrays must all be same length. The raw column is missing an element.

Comment: @JuanCamiloRiveraPalacio you were right, I edited the question. Thank you

Comment: from pyspark.sql.window import Window ?

Comment: @VK_217 yes, you are right. thank you. edited as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the window for the functions `min` and `max`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'new_col',
    F.when(
        (F.min('raw').over(w) < F.min('min_col').over(w)) | 
        (F.max('raw').over(w) > F.min('max_col').over(w)), 1
    ).otherwise(0)
)

df2.show()
+---+-------+---+-------+-------+
| id|min_col|raw|max_col|new_col|
+---+-------+---+-------+-------+
|  1|      2|  1|      3|      1|
|  1|      2|  5|      4|      1|
|  1|      3|  2|      5|      1|
|  2|      4|  3|      6|      1|
|  2|      5|  4|      7|      1|
|  2|      6|  3|      8|      1|
+---+-------+---+-------+-------+
```